# Console error, not sure way

Tags: angularjs

I am getting this error.. not sure what's the problem..

TypeError: StatisticsService.getStatisticsFromServer is not a function

i cant seem to see the problem, not sure what i'm doing wrong

this is the controller

```
app.controller('StatisticsCtrl',
        ['$scope',
          '$auth',
          'StatisticsService',
           function ($scope, $auth, StatisticsService) {

               var token = $auth.getToken();

               console.log('StatisticsCtrl INIT');

                function run() {
                    var data = {

                        token: token,
                        timestamp_from: moment(new Date()).unix()-30 * 24 * 3600,
                        timestamp_till: moment(new Date()).unix(),
                        order: 'duration_minutes',
                        limit: 20
                    };

//                     


                    StatisticsService.getStatisticsFromServer(data).then(function (response) {

                        console.log('syncStatistics', (response));

                                $scope.statistics = response;
                                // $scope.statistics = StatisticsService.buildStatsUsers(response.data);  //  jason comes from here



                        }, function (error) {
                        console.error(error);
                        });
                }


            run();

        }]);
```

this is the server

```
app.service('StatisticsService',
        ['apiClient', '$q', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
            function (apiClient, $q, $rootScope, $timeout) {

                var self = this;

                self.getUserProfiles = function (stats) {

                    var emails = [];

                    for (var i = 0; i < stats.length; i++) {
                        emails.push(stats[i].email);
                    }

                    console.log(emails);

                    var data2 = {
                        token: data.token,
                        profile_emails: emails
                    };

                    apiClient.getUserProfiles(data2).then(function (response2) {

                        console.log('getUserProfiles', (response2));

                        if (response2.data.length === 0 || response2.result !== "success") {
                            // TODO: show error
                            deferred.reject(response2);
                        }

                        var stats2= response2.data;

                        deferred.resolve(stats);//3

                    }
                    );


                    self.getStatisticsFromServer = function (data) {

                        var deferred = $q.defer(); //1


                        apiClient.getStatsTopMeeters(data)

                                .then(function (response) { //2

                                    console.log('externalApiConnect', response);


                                    if (response.data.length === 0 || response.result !== "success") {
                                        // TODO: show error
                                        deferred.reject(response);
                                    }

                                    var stats = response.data;

                                    stats = self.getUserProfiles(stats);

                                    deferred.resolve(stats);//3
                                }
                                , function (error) {
                                    deferred.reject(error);
                                    console.error(error);
                                });

                        return deferred.promise; //4

                    };
                };
            }]);
```

Comment: Well, the message says that StatisticsService.getStatisticsFromServer is not a function. Since you didn't post the definition of StatisticsService, we have no way to confirm and explain.

Answer (score 2):

You're defining `self.getStatisticsFromServer` inside the function `self.getUserProfiles`. So, the function indeed doesn't exist in the service until you call `getUserProfiles()` at least once. And it's replaced at each invocation. I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: i separated the two function but now it tells me that data is not declared, this is weird because data is declared in the api..